# "barely formed" vs. "only formed" — equivalent in this context?

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

On CNN today:

> It deprives Trump, who has no foreign policy experience and a **barely** formed
>   national security team...

Furthermore, any specific case that one should use *barely* instead of *only* and vice versa?

Answer (score 3):

*Barely* means "hardly at all" or "scarcely", while *only* means "exclusively", or "singularly". In terms of their definitions, the two words are no more interchangeable than the words "some" or "none".

Also, "only formed" is not an [adjective phrase](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/adjective-phrase-examples.html) you would use in English. However, you may have seen something like "His team was **only formed** very recently." In that case *only* is being used for emphasis. Similarly, you might hear something like "only a little bit" which is similar in meaning to "barely at all". Again, *only* is being used for emphasis. That's about as close as you'd get to seeing these words used interchangeably.

Answer (score 2):

The word *barely* is not synonymous with *only* in this context. A better synonym, I think, would be *newly*:

> It deprives Trump, who has no foreign policy experience and a newly-formed national security team...

The word *barely* in this news article is emphasizing that Trump's national security team was only recently assembled and therefore they are relatively inexperienced working in their current roles.

This interpretation aligns with this Macmillan definition:

> **[barely](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/barely)** (*adv.*) used for emphasizing that something happened only a very short time before something else

Comment: Took the words right out of my mouth.

Comment: **newly** removes much of the meaning of **barely**.  If something is "barely formed", it is almost *inchoate*. There is more to *barely* than mere recency.

Comment: @TRomano - No argument from me. Well said.

Answer (score 1):

*The word **only** cannot modify modifiers which are formed from the past participle of the verb.*

> The food platter was **only touched**. <sup>ungrammatical, without further context that might show an ellipsis</sup>
>
> The food platter was **barely touched**. Little of the food had been eaten.

If **only** appears next to a past participle, it modifies the predicate, not the predicate adjective:

> The car **was only** scratched, not dented.

**barely** modifies modifiers which express the idea of *state* or *condition*.

If something is *barely legible*, it is very difficult to read because it is almost illegible. You can make out the words on the page but only with considerable difficulty.

If something is *barely audible*, it is something you must strain to hear. It is so quiet that you might not hear it if you were not listening for it.

When **only** modifies an adverbial modifier, the modified word expresses *time*.

> The team was formed *only recently*.

**barely formed**, because of the meaning of **formed**, does not express mere recency.  It expresses the idea of a *marginal degree* of formedness. The state of being formed has been only marginally attained. The team has not really fully taken shape.  It is still *in the process* of taking shape, coming together, not yet acting fully as a team. The team is just a little better organized than disorganized.

Answer (score 0):

Please note the subtle difference in the [two meanings](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/barely) of barely.

For one, it is

> used for emphasizing that something happened only a very short time
>   before something else.

This meaning is quite close to your interpretation of '`only formed`'.

In another sense, '`barely`' is also

> used for saying that something almost does not happen or exist, or is
>   almost not possible.

This meaning is more synonymous with words like '`scarcely`', '`hardly`' and so on.

So, depending on which meaning of '`barely`' fits your context more appropriately, you can pick and choose. If it's is the first one, you may (again, be cautious with your context) use it interchangeably with '`only`'.

Comment: Your answer is not very clear. For the "short time ago" meaning, it would be **only recently formed** or **formed only recently** or **formed only a week ago**,  where **only** would modify the time phrase, not the past participle of the verb.